# Jquery listener on an element when it display:block/none; property changes

Tags: jquery, client-side-validation

Is this possible? I want an event to fire when this happens.

Comment: when does the property change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, why do you need this? Instead, I would suggest thinking about what causes the element to be shown/hidden and react to that. It's always better to decouple your logic from view.

But if you still **really** want to do this, the only way I can think of right now is to have an interval that keeps polling for the element's visibility.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) to do this.

```
$('div.myClass:hidden').livequery(function(){
//do something when hidden
});
$('div.myClass:visible').livequery(function(){
//do something when visible
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for all your great answers everyone, This Live query thing like a suitable alternative, I'm not crazy on using potentailly slow plugins when its not necessary though. My reason for needing this, I want to make some additional styles after .net sends back client-side-validation. I.E the requiredfieldvalidator will trigger, but I want to also apply <li class="invalid"> to the LI containing the field